# IT Hit WebDAV with server side console application

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Does anyone know the way to access [IT Hit WebDAV Server](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server)'s files from server side console application?

The **DavContext** generated inherits **DavContextBaseAsync** that depends on OwinContext or HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mount file system using 'net use' command:

```
net use https://server/path/
```

Behind the scenes this command is using mini-redirector driver. After mounting you can use regular file system API and commands to manage the files on a WebDAV server.

Note that:

- Your server must use Basic, Digest, NTLM, Kerberos authentication or
  be anonymous. It does not support cookies/Forms authentication.
- If you are using Basic authentication you need to use SSL/HTTPS or
  enable insecure Basic authentication (for testing and dev purposes
  only!)
- If you are using 'net use' on the Windows Server you need to have
  Desktop Experience Windows feature installed. By default this feature
  is not installed on Windows Server.